# How to import external library and cast it to <any> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript was giving me a compile error that I didn't know how to fix when trying to use a React component I defined:

```
import App = require('./components/views/app/app');
```

That error went away when I used the import module as `<any>`:

```
import App = require('./components/views/app/app');
const App2 = App as any;
```

**Is there any way to do this in one line, like so?**

```
import App = require('./components/views/app/app') as <any>;
```

It would be a great way to import JavaScript files too, without having to do this:

```
declare module 'react-router' {
    const x: any;
    export = x; 
}
```

Comment: @Blackus answer is the way to go but beware, when casting to `any`, you **opt-out** of typing (and then what is the point of using Typescript ?)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Sure, if typings are available for the lib, better to use it!

Comment: Absolutely. But a lot of the time I run into syntax errors I can't fix, where there are no public typings (like react-css-modules).  Then you need <any>. E.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675920/jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the components you have defined, it depends on how you export them, but you can use `import` statement.

For example, the exported component

```
export class FooComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
}
```

And the import

```
import {FooComponent} from './foo-component.ts';
```

For the question on the title "*How to import external library and cast it to any*", you can simply `require` on a variable.

```
const myLib: any = require('myLib');
```